# Putting existing figures together as subplots - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

Suppose I have a series of 36 2D graphs, created with some Python routine and saved as .pdf files. I want to stack them in a single plot, using each of them as a subplot. The final plot will have 6 x 6 subplots. Is that possible with Python? The original graphs are given and untouchable, I cannot modify or reuse the code used to produce them.

Comment: But you have the figures or axes? Or just the pdfs? And what kind of graphs are those?

Comment: Since "the original graphs are given and untouchable", this problem is unrelated to matplotlib. You need to ask how to merge 36 pdf files into a single output page in python. Apparently [pypdf2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2/1.26.0) would be capable of doing this (although I don't know how). There is also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/366490/how-to-merge-multiple-pdf-files-onto-one-page-with-pdftk) and you may find other related ones.